# Update Generic list<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I am looking a way to update index property of generic list Item.

For example I have a class:

```
public class ItemInfo
{
        public int SRNO { get; set }

        public Name{ get; set }
}
```

now I have `List<ItemInfo> myList` with number of items.

and want to update ItemInfo.SRNO of each Item with incremented value

like if list item has 10 items then "SRNO" should be update like

```
1
2
.
.
.
10
```

Comment: What do you need it for? You can get this index by simply iterating with a for() loop over the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you don't need LINQ like this:

```
infoList.Select((info, i) => { info.SRNO = i + 1; return info });
```

or

```
Enumerable.Range(0, infoList.Count).Select(i =>
    {
        var info = infoList[i];
        info.SRNO = i+1;
        return info;
    });
```

---

Use simple `for`-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < infoList.Count; i++)
{
    info[i].SRNO = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Abatishchev for your quick response 
But I don`t want looping ..

Which one is good for performance looping or LINQ ?

Comment: linq is looping underneath the extension method. there are no magical ways to avoid loops (which im affraid people think is what happening when you use linq)

Answer (score 1):

you will have to do it imperative. LINQ does not support side effects (by design) so you will have to iterate over you list using and imperative construct such as a for loop.

```
for(var i = 0;i<infoList.Count;){
    infoList[i].SRNO = ++i;
}
```

you can violate quite a few of the intentions of the linq methods and make them do things they were not designed to. E.g have where project or select manipulate data (at least through references. But they were never designed for that and the resulting code is usually an eyesore.

Use the constructs that suits your need in your particular case use something that was meant to create side effects.